# How to prevent Nuget from updating automatically package (minor) versions?

Tags: visual-studio, package, nuget

In the VS solution, I have as dependencies (in the packages.config file)

- a package A, version 2.0.0 which has dependency on package B version >= 5.0.0.0. The latest version of A is 2.1.0 and has the same dependencies as in 2.0.0
- a package B, version 10.0.0.0. The latest version is 10.0.5.2

I want to update the package A to 2.1.0 so I tried the command

```
update-package A
```

in 'package manager console'. But strangely, Nuget updates also the package B to 10.0.5.2.

Someone told me that by default, Nuget will update to the 'bug fix' version, but I haven't found the link about that.

Does anyone know how to tell Nuget to not update other packages automatically ?

For info, I'm using Nuget 2.5, so according to http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning, the dependencies are no longer updated during package installation

Thanks.

Comment: Are these your own internal NuGet packages, or to they exist in the official NuGet repository? If the latter, it would perhaps help if you could specify which packages and which versions you are experiencing this problem with.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, this cannot be done, and is the main reason we created the [ProGet Client Tools](http://inedo.com/company/news/announcing-proget-20-and-proget-client-tools).

You might be able to get away with specifying the explicit version by surrounding it in brackets (e.g. `[10.0.0.0]`) in the packages.config file but that still seemed to grab the bug fix version when I tried it - though I haven't tested it on the latest version yet.

For reference, the NuGet dependency version selection algorithm is described in detail here: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/nuget-versioning-part-2-core-algorithm.html

Comment: That link to the NuGet dependency version algorithm is a bit old, and things might have changed now with the release of NuGet 2.5 (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.5#Dependencies_are_no_longer_unnecessarily_updated_during_package_installation), note particularly the part about _Dependencies are no longer unnecessarily updated during package installation_. Fore more details, take a look at the related work item (https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1681) and discussion thread (https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/436712).